# If cell in column contains specific word then cut the row of the specific word

Tags: excel, vba

I want a vba that search for "POS" word in the column E, and then cut the rows of the "POS" ones, and paste it into another worksheet.

[image]

Here is the code that I tried. However, it only cut first POS row. I would be really happy if you could help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zZ5Y.png)

```
    Dim I As Long
   For I = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If CStr(Cells(I, "E").Value) = "POS" Then
             Rows(I).EntireRow.Cut
             
 Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want. Now show us what you have tried in your question and explain the problem you had getting it to work.

Comment: You don't need vba for this. You can simply filter, select table, cut and paste and finally unfilter. If you need VBA for automation purposes you can write code that does exactly the steps I mentioned. As @braX said you need to provide the code yourself and update your question with problems that you may have with your code. People here can then help you with debugging, or even rewriting the code.

Comment: Hello, I just editted the first message. I need this vba for automation purposes. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Do you need to paste the cut rows one after the other starting from second row of the other worksheet, or in the same row as existing cut ones?

Comment: Hello. One after the other starting from second row of the new worksheet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the next code, please (adapted to search in C:C the string occurrence):

```
Sub TestCutSUBRowsPaste()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, strSearch As String
 Dim i As Long, rngCut As Range, lastRowD As Long, lastRow As Long
 
 strSearch = "POS"
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set shDest = Worksheets.aDD
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To lastRow
    If InStr(sh.Range("C" & i).Value, strSearch) > 0 Then
        lastRowD = shDest.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        sh.Rows(i).Cut shDest.Range("A" & lastRowD + 1)
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

How many such occurrences do you estimate to exist in your sheet to be processed? If a lot of them, I can adapt the code to use arrays and work fast enough for big ranges to be moved...

Edited:

The faster code variant, working in memory and dropping the processing result at once:

```
Sub TestCutSUBRowsPasteArrays()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, strSearch1 As String, strSearch2 As String
 Dim arr As Variant, arrCut As Variant, rngCut As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
 Dim k As Long, i As Long, j As Long
 
 strSearch1 = "POS": strSearch2 = "Iyzico"
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set shDest = Worksheets.Add
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 'determine of the last (existing) column:
 lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 'load all the range to be processed in an array:
 arr = sh.Range("A2", sh.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
 'initially redim the array at the total range dimesions
 ReDim arrCut(1 To lastCol, 1 To UBound(arr, 1))
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If InStr(arr(i, 3), strSearch1) > 0 Or _
                      InStr(arr(i, 3), strSearch2) > 0 Then
        'if one of the search string exists:
        k = k + 1 'increment the array row
        For j = 1 To lastCol
            arrCut(j, k) = arr(i, j) 'load the final array with cut elements
            arr(i, j) = "" 'eliminate the elements from initial array
        Next
    End If
 Next i
 'if no occurrences found, the code will exit:
 If k = 0 Then MsgBox "No occurrence foung in column C:C...": Exit Sub
 'Redim the array to the exact limit containing values:
 ReDim Preserve arrCut(1 To lastCol, 1 To k)
 'dropping the initial array (remained) values:
 sh.Range("A2", sh.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value = arr
 'Dropping the processed array (arrCut) at once:
 shDest.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrCut, 2), _
        UBound(arrCut, 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrCut)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works pretty well. There will be more than 15000 rows in the real excel sheet. I would be appreciated if you can adapt it to work faster. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Do you have some other columns after E:E? The code can determine the last column, but if the columns range ends at E:E column it would be simpler...

Comment: Sir the columns ends at K:K.

Comment: @Anil Sargin: OK. I will make the code to determine the last column (from the first row). You maybe will add some other columns if needed...

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Adapted and commented its lines in order to be easily understood. Please, check it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Even though it works in my example worksheet, it does not work with the original data. I am adding the screenshot of original excel data to the first post. Can you help me to figure out how to modify the codes that you wrote? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anil Sargin: I looked to your sheet picture, but I cannot see anything like "POS" in any column. In E:E, where the code searches are not strings at all. Which will be your search string (instead of "POS") and in which column will it be found? Did you  try understanding the code logic? At least the first variant, which is easily to be understood, I think...

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Do you need to search for string "POS" inside the cells value? Meaning that "A BANK POS HESABI" should be considered a match? And, if yes, the code must be adapted to search in column C:C instead of E:E...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I am appreciated. Yes exactly that is what I am trying to do. POS should be searched inside of the cells value. "A BANK POS HESABI" and "B BANK POS HESABI" should be considered as a match. I changed the C:C column to E:E, however even it creates new worksheet, it does not cut and paste the datas. In the first code I changed the E to C in a way that If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = strSearch Then...

Comment: I tried to understand the code logic. I am sorry for my elementary questions. I understand the code logic of first variant, though faster variant seems pretty complicated.

Comment: @Anil Sargin: It certainly does not "cut and paste". It now searches a match between the `strSearch` and the cell value. I will adapt it to search the string inside the cell value string...

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Adapted the code to fulfill the new requirements. Please, test it. If it will work as needed, we here tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: A lot of thanks for your afford sir. The faster variant gave an error of "Subscript out of range". Although first one works pretty well, it makes the bigger worksheet stuck.

Comment: @Anil Sargin: When you talk about an error, it is mandatory to say on which code line it appears. Otherwise, I very seldom can deduce where to check and I do not like wasting my time, even if I like helping people... Do you have merged cells in your sheet to be processed?

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Still alive? I will leave my office in some minutes...

Comment: Actually excel did not show the code line. It only says Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: @Anil Sargin: If not something confidential, can you post a link to your workbook?

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1f89fa0c617d9eabe00fa7c4b301eba920200713091015/fe9d81. thank you

Comment: @Anil Sargin: Soved workbook [here](https://easyupload.io/ntkrnx). I copied the code in Module1. I did not have time to check what is in your sheet code, before mine. I only could see a comment saying something like "copy POS and Iyzico". Do you also need to copy rows for a second search string? I can see that I copied the updated code over the existing one being commented. I will try commenting it, too. Adapted the code for a second search string...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I will try to search for second string that is "Izyco" but I will try to make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: What is wrong with the above code? I am addressing to the one voting it down...

Comment: @Anil Sargin: But I adapted to code to accept the second string. I mean, only the second (faster) variant. You can adapt by your own the first one, if for unknown reasons you prefer it...